# ANOVA or Fisher's Exact?

Tags: anova, fishers-exact-test

I need to compare (check for any statistical significance)  eight groups (categorical data: group A-H) for which I have only the frequencies (ranging from 4-40) which are one point data (No replicate values). I have values for these eight groups for males and females separately (2 x 8 ?). 
Can I carryout an ANOVA for my comparison between the groups within one gender, and to compare between genders or do I have to do a Fisher's exact test as I do not have replicates?
Please explain, for I am a complete novice in statistics

Edit: Actually 148 humans were tested for the group (A-H) of bacteria they harbour, and one subject /human has exclusive one of the eight groups. In other words, the total of the frequencies under each group adds up to 148

Comment: Take a look at this reference: http://rcompanion.org/handbook/, there is a section on choosing a statistical test, around page 130+

Comment: [Here's a direct link](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/D_03.html) to the page Dave2e mentioned in his comment.

Comment: What is being counted in each 'cell' of the table $2 \times 8$ table? For example, if the count in cell `A-Female` is `17` please explain what happened 23 times. In particular, is that more like "17 Yes out of 50 Yes/No choices," more like "17 visits to a web site last week," or something else?

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments!